# What happens to a console.log if the developer tools are not open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm assuming it's just a noop but I'm curious in the engine if this is just conditioned off or if it still gets executed but it's not visible?

Comment: It depends - It will depend upon the implementation of the individual JS engines. You would have to go and look at the source code (where it's available).

Comment: You will still see the logs if you open the dev tools afterwards.

Comment: _“If the console is not open when the printer operation is called, implementations should buffer messages to show them in the future up to an implementation-chosen limit (typically on the order of at least 100).”_ — From the [console spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer).

Comment: @phuzi - `console` isn't part of JavaScript and isn't implemented by the JavaScript engine. It's provided by the host environment (or not :-) ).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the environment. In an environments that adhere to [the console specification](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer), then:

> If the console is not open when the printer operation is called, implementations should buffer messages to show them in the future up to an implementation-chosen limit (typically on the order of at least 100).

Some environments don't adhere to that specification (notably **very** obsolete versions of Internet Explorer [IE8 didn't even define the `console` object if the devtools weren't open(!)]), but by and large that's how it works in even vaguely modern environments.